# Pop!_OS Hibernation root partition,, boot into initramfs

Tags: boot

I have an issue with my ubuntu 22.04 based Pop!_OS.

I configured it to suspend and hibernate. It worked beautifully well for months. Last time I opened the lit of my notebook it did not come back from hibernate but booted into initramfs.

I booted into the recovery partition of Pop and ran blkid.

Output:

/dev/nvme0..p2

This is the recovery partition.

p3 is the root partition.

$fsck -l /dev/nv..p3

only stated fsck from util-linux 2.37.2

I tried to mount the drive with

$mount -a does do anything

mount /dev/nv...p3 /mnt/drive

unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'

I used gparted to open the encryption and

then tried

$sudo parted -l

Error: /dev/mapper/nvm..p3_crypt: unrecognised disk label

Model: Linux...

Disk /dev/mapper/nvm..p3_crypt: 1019 GB

Sector size: 512/512

Partition table: unknown

Disk Flags:

Then I can see the loop and the data swap

and then the nvm...p1 with partition table gpt

sudo gdisk /dev/nvm..p3 or /dev/mapper/nvm...p3_crypt gave me

MBR: not presend

BSD: not presend

APM: not presend

GPT: not presend

Creating new GPT entries in memory

I ran gparted and could see the drive. It is encrypted and it was shown as 0% free. Which to me is a surprise because it was only 10% used, new setup etc. Maybe it is shown as 100% used because it is encrypted.

Not sure. I am not a Unix or techie guy.

Information in gparted on the drive stated: Encryption: LUKS

path was empty

UUID was a long string

Status: closed

And then filesector and last sector etc.

I could open the encryption in gparted. I immediately got the message in my terminal:

/dev/mapper/nvm...p3_crypt: unrecognised disk label

If I then open the information it shows me logical volues root and swap

The status is active.

trying to mount dev/mapper/nvm...p3_crypt gave me the error

unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'

mount -a again did nothing

In gparted I could see no flags and no name.

What can I do to attach this drive and boot into?

I guess I can reinstall Pop, because the drive is visible in gparted, but there must be another solution. I have a backup of my home data but I spent lots of time to setup swapping, hibernation and various tools such as vpn, which I believe are not on the backup or only partially.

Additionally, I lose confidence and fear I have to reinstall the OS again and again after having hibernated the system. Which is no option to me. Another, quicker, easier solution is well appreciated.

Thanks.